# readline function returning empty string

Tags: python, readline

I am new to Python; little experience in programming C++. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956626/python-readline-not-working) question but it doesn't address my problem.

> Python 2.7.9, 64-bit AMD, Windows 7 Ultimate, NTFS, administrator privileges & no "read only" attribute on file to be read.

I want to create a list of strings which fulfill a certain criteria, the strings are lines of the file(see notepad.cc/diniko93).So I wrote the following function-

```
def makeLineList( filePtr, ptr ):
    lines = []
    while True:
        s = filePtr.readline()
        if not s=="":
            s = s[3:]
            s = s.split()
            if s[0].isdigit():
                print("O")
                lines.append(s)
            elif s[0] in {"+", "-"}:
                print("U")
                lines.append(s)
        else:
            print("none")
            break
    filePtr.seek(ptr, 0);    #I did this to restore file pointer, so other functions accessing this file later don't misbehave
    return lines
```

and the 2 possible main()-like (pardon my ignorance of python) bodies that I am using are-

```
with open("./testStage1.txt", 'r') as osrc:
    osrc.seek(291, 0)
    L = makeLineList( osrc, osrc.tell())
    print "".join(L)
```

and the other one-

```
osrc = open("./testStage1.txt", 'r')
osrc.seek(291, 0)
L = makeLineList( osrc, osrc.tell())
print "".join(L)
osrc.close()
```

both the times the output on terminal is a disappointing `none`

**Please Note** that the code above is minimum required to reproduce the problem and not the entire  code.

**EDIT:**
Based on @avenet's suggestion, I googled & tried to use iter (`__next__` `obj.next()` in python 3.3+ or `next(obj)` in 2.7) in my code but the problem persists, I am unable to read next line even if I call `next(osrc)` from inside the function check out these 2 snippets

- [version2](http://ideone.com/q5f9jp) next used only in main()-ish part transform_line function is not called. Calling next() 3 times produces desirable/expected output **but** in
- [version3](http://ideone.com/4nJGvy) I get a *list index out of range* error, even for lists[0] which definately has a digit

**EDIT 2:** I tried [scope check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-python) inside my functions as `if not osrc in locals():` and in next line with proper indent `print("osrc not reachable")`. And the output is `osrc not reachable`. I also tried using `from tLib import transform_line` from a temporary tLib.py but with identical results. Why is osrc not available in either case?

**EDIT 3:** Since the problem appears to be of scope.
So to avoid passing of file variable- make a function whose sole purpose is to read a line. The decision to get next line or not depends upon returned value of a function like isLineUseful()

```
def isLineUseful( text, lookFor ):
    if text.find(lookFor)!=-1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
def makeList( pos, lookFor ):
    lines = []
    with open("./testStage1.txt", 'r') as src:
        src.seek(pos)
        print(src.read(1))
        while True:
            line = next(src)
            again = isLineUseful(line, lookFor)
            if again==0:
                src.seek(pos)
                break
            else:
                lines.append(line)
    return lines

t = makeList(84, "+")
print "\n".join(t)
```

Tried it, it works perfectly on this(notepad.cc/diniko93) sample testStage1.txt.

So my programming issue is solved (thanks to responders :D) & I am marking this as answered but posting a new question about the anomalous/ behavior of `readline()` & `__next__`.

P.S. I am still learning the ways of python so I would be very happy if you could suggest a more *pythonic* & *idomatic* version of my code above.

Comment: One thing where Python is easy to work is with files...

Comment: This doesn't directly address your problem, but you should probably replace your `i+=1;  lines[i] = s` lines with `lines.append(s)`.

Comment: Also, you don't need semicolons to end a statement in Python, unless you want to put two statements on a single line, and you almost never want to do that.

Comment: If you want that every line of your file is an element of your list, then you are making your like harder than it should be...

Comment: Thanks @Kevin I was treating list like strings.

Comment: `lines[i] = s` doesn't work if `lines` is a string, either ;-)

Comment: @BhargavRao I am pretty sure I haven't reached the end of file. There are at least 50 lines after that & my loop doesn't even run once- it just prints `none` on terminal

Comment: How about the obvious scenario: No line in the file starts with a digit or `+` or `-`, and the `none` is caused by `readline()` returning the empty string on EOF?

Comment: Is the `else` part mismatched?

Comment: It would be very helpful to see a sample input file that reproduces your problem. I tried running your code on a file filled with lines of digits, and I got a whole lot of output as expected.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I'll keep that in mind. Anyway I did that to save reduce no. of lines in question.

Comment: Are you using the [Markdown package](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/) to read in that `testStage1.md`? Can you confirm that it is getting read in to begin with?

Comment: That notepad.cc page appears to be blank.

Comment: All of your lines start with "<P>". "<" is not a digit, and it's not "-" or "+", so it makes sense that none of those conditions in your code would succeed. You're using `strip`, right? Are you sure you're using it right? Remember, just calling strip does nothing if you don't assign the result. `s.strip("<P>")` has no effect, you have to do `s = s.strip("<P>")`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker please take a look at my edits. And +1 if you think I show research effort & clarity, this question needs to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the lines your way:

```
def transform_line(line):
    if line != "":
        if line[0].isdigit():
            print("O")
        elif line[0] in {"+", "-"}:
            print("U")
    else:
        print("None")
    return line

with open("./testStage1.txt", 'r') as osrc:
    osrc.seek(291)
    lines = [transform_line(line) for line in osrc]
    #Do whatever you need with your line list
```

If you don't want to transform lines just do this:

```
with open("./testStage1.txt", 'r') as osrc:
    osrc.seek(291)
    lines = list(osrc)
    #Do whatever you need with your line list
```

Or just implement a line iterator if you need to stop on a certain condition:

```
def line_iterator(file):
    for line in file:
        if not line[0].isdigit() and not line in ["+", "-"]:
            yield line
        else:
            break

with open("./testStage1.txt", 'r') as osrc:
    osrc.seek(291)
    lines = list(line_iterator(osrc))
    #To skip lines from the list containing 'blah'
    lines = [x for x in lines if 'blah' not in line]
    #Do whatever you need with your line list
```

Comment: Ok, but from the OP's `osrc.seek(291, 0);` line, it seems like he wants to skip the first 291 characters. How should he do that if he iterates over the lines of the file this way?

Comment: Let's implement an iterator, my friend!!

Comment: @avenet I followed your advice- please check out the **Edit** in question & let me know whats wrong . . .

Comment: @newPython Do my solution gives you a list? As I see on your Edit, you are trying to use next, next will only work with an iterable element, on a list it won't work.

Comment: @newPython The list created on the lines variable already gives you the filtered data. What else do you need?

Comment: @avenet Yes your code gives me list of all lines beyond 291. Google says both list & files are iterable

Comment: I don't see how the list is filtered. I still have to process each line. Here is what I am trying to get- add only those lines to list which contain a special starting substring, thereby minimizing memory usage & keeping list short.

Comment: Ohh, OK, if you want to filter the strings that contain a special substring I will add it on the answer

Comment: So if the line contains a special character, we will ignore it and go to the next one, is that what you want?

Comment: @avenet thanks a lot man :) your ideas helped me solve my programming issue & shed some light on iters. If I don't get any answers about behavior of readline() soon I'll mark your answer as "accept"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not using Python as it should be used. The purpose of using a language like Python is to write just fewer lines of code to achieve the same result of other snippets of code in other programming languages, such as C++ or Java.

It's not necessary to pass a file pointer as a function parameter to read the file, you can open directly the file within the function to which you pass the filename.

Then you can call this function with the file name and store the list in a variable that you will eventually manipulate. If you are not familiar with exceptions handling, you could for example use a function from the module `os` to check if the file already exists: `os.path.exists(filename)`.

If you want to search for a pattern in the line you are currently using, you can simply use an if statement (there are a lot of ways of doing that, this is just an example):

```
if line not in list_of_strings_you_want_not_to_include: 
    lines.append(line)
```

If you to check if the pattern is at the beginning, you can use the `startswith` string function on the line:

```
if not str(line).startswith("+"):
    lines.append(line)
```

If you want to skip a certain amount of characters, you can use the `seek` function (as you are effectively using). This is just a way that uses more lines of code, but it's still very simple:

```
def read_file(filename, _from):
    lines = []
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            file.seek(_from)
            for line in file:
                lines.append(line)     
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('file not found')
    return lines

filename = "file.txt"
lines = read_file(filename, 10)
```

Much easier, you can also do this, instead of iterating explicitly through all lines:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    file.seek(_from)
    return list(file)
```

Or using your favourite function `readlines`:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    file.seek(_from)
    return file.readlines()
```

The purpose and the advantage of iterating explicitly through all lines is that you can do a lot of checking and whatever you want with the lines or characters in the right moment you are reading, so I would adopt certainly the first option I suggested above.

Comment: Ok, but from the OP's `osrc.seek(291, 0);` line, it seems like he wants to skip the first 291 characters. How should he do that if he iterates over the lines of the file this way?

Comment: I passed the pointer because I am using a different functions.py file in my program. I `import pyFunctions`

Comment: IMHO `readlines()` would be much better that reading all lines in a list as your 1st code snippet suggests.

Comment: @newPython It's not necessary, you just have to pass the filename

Comment: @newPython Why is it much better?

Comment: @nbro because someone told me 1. inbuilt functions are always better. 2. readlines() manages memory & buffer stuff better & 3. I am simply scared of using n>1 lines of code if a single statement could do it.

Comment: @newPython So use your `readlines` and don't ask questions again, right? What's your problem then? I simply cannot understand why you are asking help if you cannot even try to understand new things...

Comment: whoa nbro, calm down.

Comment: ```if line not in ("+", "-", "Barack Obama")``` will only work if ```line``` is exactly one of those things.  OP wants to match on the first item of a sequence - ```s[0]```.

Comment: @wwii It's just an example.

Comment: @wwii My question does not aim to be a tutorial. I have already been very patient with the OP, whose question is very unclear. If it was my question, it would have already been downvoted of -20

Comment: @nbro thanks for the alternatives but could u explain just why `readline()` isn't working as expected?? Considering that everything in above codeblocks is all the code I have in 1 .py file.

Comment: @newPython Give me some moment and I will try to check your problem ;)

Comment: @newPython I will try to analyse your code line by line. `if not s == "":`, you probably want to say, if `s` is different from `""`, which you can achieve easily (like in C++) with `if s != "":`

Comment: @newPython The problem of your code is certainly this: you're reading from the `291` character forward, but at that point there's no character in the file, and `readline` returns always `""`, an empty string (of course), that's why it jumps directly to the `else` statement and prints `none`. I don't know how your file looks like (how many lines...), but try using a smaller number, like 5 or 10 and see if something changes...

Answer (score 0):

You try to process this input:

```
<P> unnecessart line </P>
<P> Following is an example of list </P>
<P> 1. abc </P>
<P>     + cba </P>
<P>     + cba </P>
<P>             + xyz </P>
```

Now in your brain, you just see the important bits but Python sees everything. For Python (and any other programming language), each line starts with `<`. That's why the `if`'s never match.

If you stripped the `<P>`, be sure to strip the spaces as well because

```
1. abc
    + cba
```

the second line starts with a space, so `s[0]` isn't `+`. To strip spaces, use `s.trim()`.